# Documentation of the Erlang shell function i(), or which module exports it?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I'm trying to find documentation on the `i()` shell function, which is recommended for [inspecting memory consumption](http://www.erlang.org/faq/how_do_i.html#idp32777520).  I can't figure out what module exports that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell first tries to evaluate local functions from [shell module](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/shell.erl#L947) but `i/0` is not there and second place [to look](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/shell.erl#L1046) is [shell_default module](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/shell_default.erl) and you can follow `i()` to implementation in [c module](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/c.erl#L282).